# Indexing content for Joomla smart search must be repeated every few days

Tags: smartsearch

In Joomla 3.4.1 I'm using smart search and K2 for content.
The content is indexed and it works ok - for a few days.
Then I type a word in the search box and nothing is found. I go back to admin and find out that no content is indexed anymore and must index it again.

How do I make sure the content is indexed without my interevention all the time?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Have you enabled the Content - Smart Search plugin?

Comment: Yes, I sure did

Answer (score 1):

There is also a Smart Search - K2 plugin, do you have it enabled?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Sorry, I can't add comments yet, just trying to help ;)
You can delete the answer if you think it's not helpfull

Comment: Yes, sure I have it enabled.